# how Could we control magnetic fields around us effectively?

Tags: science-based, magic, space, environment, science-in-society

I'm trying to write a story where a character controls the magnetism around him, how would this effect him and the world around him, what can potentially be his weaknesses?

Comment: This question is extremely broad, probably too broad for this site.  You can edit it to make it less broad.

Comment: I would also remove science-based as a tag, because... well, a character who can mentally produce magnetic fields isn't anywhere near the realm of "science-based".

Comment: You cannot control externally generated magnetic fields, because they are out of your control.  You can possibly generate your own magnetic field to interfere with them to some extent.  As to what's your character weakness ?  Your choice : blindness, deafness, constant headaches ...

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like the Marvel Comics character Magneto from the X-Men. Ultimately, direct manipulation of magnetic fields in a world where we rely on metal and electricity makes you more powerful than you may think. That said, if you do some research on Magneto, you'll have answers to this question as asked.

The one area of magnetic field control that's *not* covered by Magneto however is precision. I've always wondered what would happen if Magneto practiced at very small, precise field manipulations. Could he rewrite data on HDDs for instance? Would that just be too time consuming for him? Could he directly change electrical flow on an integrated circuit (CPU/GPU) and therefore directly alter program behaviour?

The weakness is obvious; someone manipulating fields to any degree is going to be VERY easy to detect with the right equipment. His EM signature is probably quite large meaning that he's not the stealthiest person out there when people know what to look for.

Also, typing an email when you're angry is going to be a nightmare as you'll overload your computer pretty spectacularly unless you have great control. Same with light bulbs, and given that smart phones use magnetic fluctuations (capacitance) to detect touch, they're going to be almost impossible to use in a conventional sense unless you can completely switch off this power.

In point of fact, if this is an always on ability, given the miniaturisation of technology comes at the expense of hardiness, this ability would increasingly lock you out of the digital age by making new electronics too sensitive for you to even be near, let alone use.

Comment: I love the image of Magneto getting frustrated with his smartphone as he tries to do something mundane.  *Arrrgh, stupid WebMail!*

Comment: Ha! love it. On the other hand, perhaps he could be his own personal Bluetooth device? :)

Comment: "Could he rewrite data on HDDs for instance?" Let's say he is only trying to change a pronoun in a word doc... how long would it take him to convert from binary to hexa to utf-8 (or whichever encoding) to xml to zip - in his head - and that only to find the right place in the doc? I can't imagine him doing this to, dunno, create a backdoor in a nuclear missile control system's software. :D